# cannot inject the @value defined in application.properties when use mock test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

How can I inject the value defined in application.properties when I do a mockito test.

Service.java

```
@Override
public String getUseLanguage() {
    return applicationProperties.getLanguage();
}
```

ApplicationProperties.java

```
public class ApplicationProperties {

    @Value("${language}")
    private String Language;

    public String getLanguage() {
        return Language;
    }
```

application.properties

```
Language = EN;
```

My test case:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TimChannelServiceTest {
@Mock
private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

@InjectMocks
private Service Service;

@Test
public void getUseLanguage(){
    assertEquals(applicationProperties.getLanguage(),Service.getUseLanguage());
    }
}
```

it seems **@Value** is not injected with the ApplicationProperties, both **applicationProperties.getLanguage()** and **Service.getUseLanguage()** are null.

Could anyone tell me how to handle this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mock the `applicationProperties` field in your test and you don't provide any behavior. That makes sense that methods invoked on return `null`.
Besides, why do you mock if you want that properties be injected as it should be ?

To test the `application.properties` values, annotate your class with `@SpringBootTest` that will load the Spring context and in this way the environment properties will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about spring @Value than you have to run your test cases with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotations along with context file which will inject Application properties class.

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
public class MyTest {
    }
```

However in you case you are mocking hence you cannot expect it to provide spring utilities.

Comment: I updated my answer. You are mocking ApplicationProperties hence it will not work. It will work only if it is managed my spring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load spring context for `@value` to work. Annotate your class with `@SpringBootTest`. Also instead of mocking your `ApplicationProperties` autowire it. And have `language` property defined in your test properties file.